# Adjusting placeholder button controls

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to put button controls onto a page through adding it to the placeholders contained within the designer. The buttons contained within the original form's placeholders work fine but the one's that are added after the button selection event don't work. The properties (ie text) work fine but the event associated with the button doesn't trigger.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebTrial
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Boolean SignUp = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetUpControls();
        }
        public void SetUpControls()
        {
            Button butSubmit = new Button(), butSignIn = new Button(), butSignUp = new Button();
            butSignIn.ID = "butSignIn";
            butSignUp.ID = "butSignUp";

            butSubmit.Text = "SUBMIT";
            butSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(butSubmit_Click);

            butSignIn.Text = "Sign In";
            butSignIn.Click += new EventHandler(butSignIn_Click);

            butSignUp.Text = "Sign Up";
            butSignUp.Click += new EventHandler(butSignUp_Click);

            if (!SignUp)
            {
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Clear();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(butSubmit);
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(butSignUp);
            }
            else
            {
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Clear();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(butSubmit);
                PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(butSignIn);
            }
        }
        protected void butSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SignInHit");        //Text does not come through
            SignUp = false;
            SetUpControls();
        }
        protected void butSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SignUpHit");        //Text does come through
            SignUp = true;
            SetUpControls();
        }
        protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SubmitHit");        //Works on the Sign In view but not the Sign Up
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain which button does not work and how it is not working?

Comment: Yeah sure - the event just isn’t triggering.  Within the console, the text SignUpHit will come through when the related button has been selected however, SignInHit will not come through. This shows that the event hasn’t triggered. The same can be shown with the Submit button. When the button is selected on the “Sign in” layout of the form, the SubmitHit text will come through to the console however, when the button is selected from the “Sign up” layout of the form, the SubmitHit text will not come through.